# Launching flask server from __main__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wsgi

I am trying to launch a flask server by running `python -m my_app`

Inside `my_app/__main__.py` I have:

```
from .main import app
app.run()
```

However when running `python -m my_app` I get:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my_app/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .main import app
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Indicating there is a problem with the relative import, however the strange thing is the flask app appears to try and run. Logically, next I removed the relative import with:

```
from my_app.main import app
```

This resulted in:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my_app/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from my_app.main import app
ImportError: No module named 'my_app'
```

Adding a bit more to `__main__.py`

```
print('1.')

from store_app.main import app
print('2.')

app.run()
print('3.')
```

Reveals this occurs when flask reloads `__main__.py`

```
1.
2.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my_app/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from my_app.main import app
ImportError: No module named 'my_app'
```

This suggests flask reloads `__main__.py` without adding the module to `sys.path`. Has anyone got a work around for this? Or is the cleanest way to manually insert the module into `sys.path`

Comment: Looks like a circular import issue

Comment: But if I add the parent dir to sys.path in `__main__.py` it works. Surely meaning it's not a circular import issue